# Send Authorized User's First Name to _Layout.cshtm from base controller in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a base controller in MVC 5 and I want pass my custom Field that I added to user's Identity to _Layout.cshtml but I can't do it
I could send another data from another models to views but I can't send my authorized user's First name to _Layout.cshtml
This is my Base Controller

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
{
    DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
    public BaseController()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use ViewBag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ViewBag`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = User.Identity.Name ?? "Anonymouse user";
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

So inside your `_Layout.cshtml` you can easily access the Name this way:

```
<span>@ViewBag.Name</span>
```

Update: if you want to retrive custom user's data, try this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
        ViewBag.Name = user != null ? user.FullName : "Aanonymouse";
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if User or User.Identity is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    System.Security.Principal.IIdentity me = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello @me.Name</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can skip the variable declaration and use "@User.Identity.Name" to access the current user's name directly.